# urlpatterns don't get updated after DB insertion?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm having an html form which inserts data into one table called srv.

I've built the urls.py in such a way to capture every insertion:

```
for item in srv.objects.all():
    linkSrv = item.loc.lower() + '/srv/' + item.subctg.lower() + '/' + item.title.lower()
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^' + linkSrv + '/$', 'beta.views.queryFromIndexDeep'),
)
```

After the one insertion is being made, e.g. loc='loc', subctg='subctg' and title='title'
if i point my browser to **127.0.0.1:8000/loc/srv/subctg/title/** i get the http404 error (no matching url)

If I 'force-save' the urls.py (vim urls.py then :x! ) - after loc,subct,title were inserted - then I can successfully access 127.0.0.1:8000/loc/srv/subctg/title/

Anyone can shed some light? It looks like the urlpatterns need to be 'updated' each time a row is insterted in srv table.

Comment: Why are you doing that? why don't you use regexp?

Comment: because im a newb in django and i managed the urlpatterns as i knew, but i am reading about regex  right now

Comment: Great, look at the answer, and look this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use something like this:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<loc>\w+)/(?P<subctg>\w+)/(?P<title>\w+)/$',
                         'beta.views.queryFromIndexDeep'),
)
```

Using regular expressions to match your view is way easier, and recommended. In your view, the above would match a function defined like `beta.views.queryFromIndexDeep(request, loc, subctg, title)`, from where you can continue to work with these variables to extract the relevant data from your defined models.

Comment: thanks, im trying it now 
loc, subctg and title should be obtained in queryFromIndexDeep by accessing the necesary model, right?

can you also tell why is it working (with my code) only after the urls.py are force-saved ?

Comment: It's working because you manually create new url definition for each entry in your database. When you create a new entry and run the updating code, only then it can find it. Using the above, in your view you can use something like `srv.objects.get(loc=loc, subctg=subctg, title=title)` to retrieve the object for the current url.

Comment: I've updated the urls.py with the above and I've set queryFromIndexDeep(request, loc, subctg, title): return render_to_response('test.html') but still I get 404 when accessing a link which matches the above pattern. What am I doing wrong ? :(

Comment: never mind, I got it ... i was having some spaces in the title and in the subctg fields .. i have to figure out how to insert them into the regex .. thanks a lot!!

Comment: For your regexes you might want something a bit more relaxed... e.g. `(?P<loc>[\w-]+)` to match words and dashes (common for url's), or perhaps even `(?P<loc>[^/]+)` to match everything up to a slash. You should experiment a little with what works out best for you.

Comment: i ended up using **(?P<title>[A-Za-z0-9 _:@-]+)** i might need to adjust it in the future, but thats alright ... thanks again - i wasted all my day figuring out this, but its going to last forever now :)

Answer (score 0):

add a slugfield (unique) to your srv model and add a method to the model

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return /yourapp/%s/ % self.slug
```

Then in urls use a pattern to match this

```
url(r'^srv/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', yourgenericview),
```

Look into the django slugify snippit for fun http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/690/